# Android Library dependent on another lib provided by the Android App

Tags: android, android-library, library-project

I am building an Android Library which rely on a third party library. This library will be provided by the main Android application.

How can I develop my library which is dependent on the third party library without including it in the compiled version of my library?

In other words, I would like to link my library against the 3rd party lib but I do not want to include it in my jar.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the other library as a seaparate project in your IDE (Eclipse or Android Studio) and defining it as a project your project is depending on in the project settings. This should achieve what you want. You might also be able to define in the build settings what is included in the build packet.

Comment: If the API is stable, this looks like it might be a job for an interface or abstract class defined by your library.  The client's code can hand you an object which implements your interface or extends your abstract class, and you will be able to use it in accordance with the properties defined by your API.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724579/android-dependencies