# Is it possible to declare that one APK depends on other APK and automatically install dependent APK

Tags: android

There is application which contains only android service (let say SERVICE_1.apk). Also there are applications (let say APP_1.apk, APP_2.apk, ...) which want to use service from SERVICE_1.apk. Is it possible to declare in some way that each of APP_n.apk depends on SERVICE_1.apk and if user will download and install APP_n.apk from google play then APP_n.apk will automatically check if there is already SERVICE_1.apk installed on device and install SERVICE_1.apk if it is not already installed.

Comment: similar but not so APK specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724579/android-dependencies

Answer (score 3):

No, Google Play does not implement any sort of dependency mechanism.

Of course, you are welcome to build your own as part of your APKs. Just check on first run to see if your dependent apps are installed and, if not, prompt the user to install them. Ideally, though, these are "soft dependencies", enabling optional features, rather than "hard dependencies" that prevent the app from running at all. Users may get irritated if they cannot use your app because they have to go download a bunch of other stuff first.