# How can I use whole android project inside a new android project

Tags: android, custom-keyboard, hindi, transliteration, indic

I have source code of [indic-keyboard](https://github.com/smc/Indic-Keyboard), and I want to use functionality of this project in my app, I have tried converting indic-project into a library, but that seems tough, so I am looking for some other workaround for this thing.

What can/have I try/tried-

1. I try to change "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'' to "apply plugin: 'com.android.library", then synced the gradle and got this some errors([check this issue](https://github.com/smc/Indic-Keyboard/issues/61)), there I got confirmation developer of indic-keyboard that it will be tough to convert it into a library as this project is an input-method which relies on system settings.
2. So now I am thinking to use whole the project within my app, such that it will compile just after the installation of my app, but I am not sure where to start, I mean what things should I remove from build.gradle of indic-keyboard so that it stop generating apk, if somehow I am able to do that then it  may not be that tough,I need just the idea how should I proceed, so if you have worked on these type of things then please provide your valuable suggestions.

*edit - I have also tried importing as module(suggested by  zgc7009) but that produces error as shown in following images[image] [image]

Comment: You can import projects as a module and compile it in your gradle file as a dependency

Comment: @zgc7009 this is showing "Select Module to import" all the time and I guess it may be because this project is an android application and not a library

Comment: No, then you select the "module" or the application project from your local drive, and upload the project as a module. You then need to add it to gradle to be compiled.

Comment: File -> new ->import module -> then selected my project folder, and then I get the error mentioned in above images, is I am doing something wrong

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your response (was in a rush). I am unfamiliar with this project and was under the impression it was a library. You can try switching it's gradle settings to a library (depending on licensing terms). Other than that, you might be restricted to having the user dl from the play store.

Comment: ok, I will look for workaround

Answer (score 0):

The Indic Keyboard is already available on the play store, I would suggest to check at runtime if the user has that package (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724579/how-to-make-an-android-app-that-depends-on-another-app)) and act accordingly: if the user has the package then fine, otherwise you can open the play store (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application))

Comment: yeah I can consider that too, but that will be my last option