# installing ffmpeg library using command line in android development

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, sdk

I have tried to run a command from the application to install the *ffmpeg* library. This is my code:

```
try {
    Process process =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/pm install ffmpeg");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Problem:**

It doesn't work and prints the output "*failed*".

Answer (score 0):

**pm** is not **apt**, and Android does not have a standard repo from which you can install **ffmpeg** (alas!). It is not clear what you want to install. If your app depends on some other app being installed from PlayStore, see [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887625/192373). If your app uses the ffmpeg binary (in form of executable or shared library), you must package it with your APK. Note that recently Google introduced [*Dynamic feature modules*](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery#dynamic_feature_modules)  - a new way to package parts of your APK so that they may be downloaded on demand. One such *feature* for your app could contain **ffmpeg**.