# Android - opencv manager & OpenCV binary package installed or not

Tags: android, opencv, android-package-managers

How can I check(Android code) whether the opencv manager & appropriate OpenCV binary packages are already installed in the android device or not?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this SO discussion:

[Android check for dependent application during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518818/android-check-for-dependent-application-during-installation)

Just check if needed applicaton is installed or not.